# R: Error in a Loop, replacement has length zero

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I tried to find the solution looking at other questions but no one fits on my needs.

I get the error in this reproducible example:

```
m <- 0

vectorsd<-  rep(0.2, 183)

dgmean <- -0.41

  rnorm <- as.data.frame(rnorm(183, mean = m, sd = vectorsd))

for (i in 1:length(rnorm$`rnorm(183, mean = m, sd = vectorsd)`))  {
  rnorm[,i] <- rnorm(183, mean = m, sd = vectorsd)
}

simulation1 <- matrix(1,184,183)

beta <- -0.21

##For each column (each value of the forward curve)
for (i in 1:length(simulation1[1,])) {
  ##For each element of a whole column (each day since the starting of the product)
  for (j in 1:length(simulation1[,1])-1) {
    simulation1[j+1,i] <- simulation1[j,i]+rnorm[j,i]+(beta*(simulation1[j,i]-dgmean))
  }
}
```

I was expecting to get each row of `simulation1` as from the second to be substituted with the transformation `simulation1[j,i]+rnorm[j,i]+(beta*(simulation1[j,i]-dgmean))` but I get this error instead:

> Error in simulation1[j + 1, i] <- simulation1[j, i] + rnorm[j, i] + (beta *  : 
>     replacement has length zero

What am I missing? I am really burning my brain trying to find the typo/error

Comment: this example is not reproducible. m, vectorsd, and dgmean are unknown. while you let us know that the former two are constant (please include them), dgmean is unclear.

Comment: @mnist I hope it is fixed now.

Comment: At the point of fault, `i` and `j` are at the offending states. You can now examine, outside of the loop, individual expression and its dimensions and see where what you expect differs from what you get.

Comment: This: `1:length(simulation1[,1])-1` results in a sequence starting wih 0. Since there are no 0 indeces in R, `simulation[0,i]` returns `numeric(0)`.

Comment: We will get prettier column names if we do: `rnorm <- data.frame(myColumn = rnorm(183, mean = m, sd = vectorsd))`

Comment: @MaxTeflon thanks, what I was actually aiming to do with that statement was detracting 1 to `length(simulation[,1])` which would result, or at least I wanted it to result, in `183`, then `1:length(simulation[,1])-1` would result in 1:183. I could do it just substituting `length(simulation[,1])-1` by 183 but for automating purposes I would like to find the way to make a seq from 1 to 183, may be I should use `seq_along()` function

Comment: `1:(length(simulation1[,1])-1)` would work too

Comment: the example is still not fixed (what mnist pointed out) just change `mean <-0 ` to `m <- 0` and it will be reproducible

Comment: @Solarion I hope it is reproducible with my new edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs without any error :

```
m <- 0
vectorsd<-  rep(0.2, 183)
dgmean <- -0.41
rnorm <- as.data.frame(rnorm(183, mean = m, sd = vectorsd))

for (i in 1:length(rnorm$`rnorm(183, mean = m, sd = vectorsd)`))  {
   rnorm[,i] <- rnorm(183, mean = m, sd = vectorsd)
}

simulation1 <- matrix(1,184,183)
beta <- -0.21

##For each column (each value of the forward curve)
for (i in 1:length(simulation1[1,])) {
  ##For each element of a whole column (each day since the starting of the product)
   for (j in 1:(length(simulation1[,1]) - 1)) {
     simulation1[i,j] <- simulation1[i,j]+rnorm[i,j]+(beta*(simulation1[i,j]-dgmean))
   }
}
```